# If the cost per minute is $\$0.032$, is the cost per hour $\$1.92$ or $1.92$¢?

Tags: arithmetic, unit-of-measure

I hope someone can help me with this problem. The cost per minute to make a phone call is $0.032, I'm that multiplying this by 60 will get total cost per hour.

```
$0.032 * 60 = 1.92
```

I'm not sure if that is a $1.92 or 1.92 ¢

Thank you

Comment: Since you started with dollars, it won't magically change to cents. If garlic is $0.50 each, buying 10 of them will be $0.50*10 = $5.00 not 5.00¢. If you want to convert dollar to cents you have to multiply by 100¢/$1. See https://www.khanacademy.org/math/cc-sixth-grade-math/cc-6th-ratios-prop-topic/cc-6th-unit-conversion/v/converting-pounds-to-ounces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Units act like special numbers multiplicatively:

$$\$0.032 = 0.032\ \textrm{dollars}.$$

The cost of a phone call is $$0.032 \frac{\textrm{dollars}}{\textrm{minute}}.$$

The cost of a 60 minute call is then

$$\require{cancel}\textrm{cost} = 0.032 \frac{\textrm{dollars}}{\cancel{\textrm{minute}}} \cdot 60\ \cancel{\textrm{minute}} = 60 \cdot 0.032\  \textrm{dollars} = 1.92\ \textrm{dollars}.$$

If we want to convert to cents, we multiply by the conversion factor:

$$1.92\ \cancel{\textrm{dollars}} \cdot \frac{100\ \textrm{cents}}{\cancel{\textrm{dollar}}} = 192\ \textrm{cents}.$$